# Converting (Corine) land cover palette to RGB within Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, rgb, colortable

I'd like to export a Corine Land Cover (CLC) Map (i.e. an image from `ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/CORINE/V20/100m")`) from Google Earth Engine go my Google Drive, forgoing the need to any external post-processing. Of course, land cover maps are natively provided as paletted images, i.e. every pixel contains just a single integer value indicating its class. For visualization purposes, however, one usually needs to convert these integer class values to RGB values. Inside GEE, this is either automatically done for standard datasets such as `CLC`, or can simply be done by defining a palette and using it as a parameter in `Map.addLayer` (option "palette"). But if you want to export the image and not manually assign a palette in, say, QGIS, you need to remap the integer class values to RGB triplets algorithmically. Is there a function to do this, either already pre-defined for CLC, or for arbitrary, to-be-defined palettes?

EDIT: I have already tried to use the `ee.Image.visualize()` function like below, but this has only given me a single constant color.

```
var CLC_palette = clc.get('landcover_class_palette');

var clc2 = clc.visualize({
  palette:CLC_palette,
  forceRgbOutput: true
})
```

Comment: Check out the `visualize()` function

Comment: Have done so already, will add details to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `visualize()` without any arguments.

```
var clc = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/CORINE/V20/100m")
  .first()
  .visualize()
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8d4b720dde9ac84d4fd1ba374c3ac031

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but this is the solution. Many thanks!